# Логин в приложении android при помощи rest как сделать?

Tags: android, android-studio, rest

В моем проекте нужно сделать функцию входа по уже имеющимся логину и паролю. То есть весь смысл приложение заключается в том что-бы быть полноценной заменой веб-сайту, и вход в приложении должен быть связан с логином на сайте. Я много уже перечитал ресурсов но все равно не сильно понимаю как это сделать. На большинстве сайтов написаны методы get но мне ведь нужно отправить данные с формы входа что-бы сервер их проверил на корректность. Есть библиотеки retrofit и volley и я думаю что буду юзать первый вариант так как он более гибкий (может и нет, я сделал это умозаключение сам) но мне не понятно как это все будет происходить ну как будет осуществляться отправка на сервер и потом ведь нужно как-то получить ответы. Если кто-то знает что мне посоветовать или чем помочь то буду очень благодарен, потому-что сейчас я не знаю с чего начинать.

Comment: При авторизации отправляете Post-запрос с логином(ну или что у вас там в качестве идентификации) и паролем на сервер. На сервере проверяете наличие такого пользователя в бд. В случае нахождения, отправляете ответный JSON в приложение, где уже проверяете JSON, и перенаправляете пользователя на другой активити (или фрагмент). Для отправки запросов я использовал как раз Retrofit 2

Comment: Если интересует, поищу пример, где пишут приложение с помощью Retrofit 2 и SLIM (php), и там как раз имеется авторизация и регистрация

Comment: если есть пример буду рад ознакомится а то мало что понятно по этой тематике пока-что

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial/